# Password length verification (c++)

Tags: c++, passwords

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

class BankAccount
{
public:
    int CheckIntegrity(int input)
    {
        int allowed[6] ={};
        int i{};
        if (input < allowed[i])
        {
            std::cout << "Accepted";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Exited with 0";

        }
        return 0;
    }

};


int main()
{
    BankAccount accounts;
    int numbers;
    std::cout << "Enter account number ";
    std::cin >> numbers;
    accounts.CheckIntegrity(numbers);
}
```

I am not sure why when I run the code in Visual Studio, it shows Exited with 0 ? Any clues on how to fix this problem. Been stuck for an hours trying to fix this

Comment: Try adding `system("pause");` at the end of main function.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to check if the length of the input is smaller or equal to 6?

Comment: You are not checking the length but the value of `input` (I guess this is not what you want by reading your title). Moreover, `int allowed[6] {};` means that you create a zero-initialized array of 6 elements which is `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. Then `int i {};` create a zero-initialized integer. So `allowed[i]` is equivalent to `allowed[0]` that is the first value of the array (hence `0` because `allowed[0] == 0`). Consequently, you are comparing the value of `input` with `0` which does not make any sense regarding what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys, what I wanted to do is if the user entered less than 6 values, it is accepted otherwise the program exits with 0

Answer (score 1):

The allowed[] array contains all zeroes. So if you input any value say x , where
 0 >= x >= INT_MAX your code would print "Exited with 0".
Any negative number should print "Accepted". May be a logical bug you have in your code.

I ran your code in Xcode. Try debugging using breakpoints if that helps.

Comment: Hey Adithya K, thanks for your reply, what I wanted to do is if the user entered less than 6 values, it is accepted otherwise the program exits with 0

Answer (score 0):

Usual way is to add breakpoint at the closing brace to check the result before exiting.

Another way is to go Tools > Options > Debugging and uncheck "Automatically close the console when debugging stops".